# Decomposition of $L^2$-spaces and singular measures

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

If $\langle \Omega, \mathfrak{F}, \mathbb{P}\rangle$ is a measure space and $L^2$ is the corresponding $L^2$ space and 
$$
K\oplus K^{\perp} \cong L^2(\mathfrak{F},\mathbb{P}).  
$$

Then let:
$$
\mathfrak{F}_1\triangleq \sigma(\{H \in K \}) \\
\mathfrak{F}_2\triangleq \sigma(\{H \in K^{\perp} \}) \\
$$

Moreover, do there exist singular measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that
$$
\mu + \nu = \mathbb{P},\\
L^2(\mathfrak{F}_1,\mu) \oplus L^2(\mathfrak{F}_2,\nu) \cong L^2(\mathfrak{F},\mathbb{P})
$$

$$
\int f d\nu =0 = \int g d\mu 
$$
if $f \in L^2(\mathfrak{F}_1)$ and $g \in \mathfrak{F}_2$?

I was thinking of using conditional measures, but I'm not sure how?

Comment: For a counterexample to the first question, can't you simply take your favorite pair of random variables $f,g$ which are mean-zero and uncorrelated but not independent, and let $K$ be the one-dimensional space spanned by $f$?

Comment: Alternatively, let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be $[0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-field and Lebesgue measure, and let $K$ be the one-dimensional space spanned by $f(x) = x$, or your other favorite one-to-one function.  It should be easy to show that $\mathcal{F}_1 = \mathcal{F}_2 = \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Ok i removed that, how about the second part?

Comment: What does $\cong$ mean?  Isomorphic? Isometric?  Isometric via the natural map?

Comment: Hilbert space isomorphic

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by $\oplus$ in the second part, since $L^2(\mathfrak{F}_1,\mu), L^2(\mathfrak{F}_2,\nu)$ as subspaces of $L^2(\mathfrak{F}, \mathbb{P})$ will typically have nontrivial intersection.  Do you really mean you want to form the formal direct sum?  Then what do you want to use for the isomorphism? It's trivial that there will exist an isomorphism in typical cases, for instance if they are all separable, so the question is, what do you want the isomorphism to be?

Comment: Why would the intersection be non-trivial if the $\sigma$-fields are constructed in this manner?  I though that $L^2(\mathfrak{F}_1,\mathbb{P})$ would be orthogonal to $L^2(\mathfrak{F}_2,\mathbb{P})$?  Instead of $\oplus$ lets use $\times$, maybe that's better.

Comment: @NateEldredge Since $\mathfrak{F} = \mathfrak{F}_1\otimes \mathfrak{F}_2$ then maybe she can construct $\nu$ and $\mu$ as some sort of disintegration of $\mathbb{P}$?

Comment: No, they will not be orthogonal in general.  See the example above, in which they are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I have completely parsed your question, but it seems to be based on an assumption that the $\sigma$-fields $\mathfrak{F}_1, \mathfrak{F}_2$ are in some sense "orthogonal".  That doesn't have to be true; they can even be equal.

Take as an example $\Omega = [0,1]$ with its Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$ and let $\mathbb{P}$ be Lebesgue measure.  Note the following fact: if $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Borel and injective with a Borel left inverse $g^{-1} : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$, then $\sigma(g)$, the smallest $\sigma$-field making $g$ measurable, is $\mathfrak{F}$ itself.  (Proof: for any Borel set $B \subset [0,1]$, the function $1_B \circ g^{-1} \circ g = 1_B$ is $\sigma(g)$-measurable.)

Let $g_1(x) = x$ and $g_2(x) = x^2 - \frac{1}{2}$.  They are orthogonal in $L^2$, so if we let $K$ be the one-dimensional space spanned by $g_1$, we have $g_2 \in K^\perp$.  But each is Borel and injective (indeed, each is a homeomorphism onto its image) so we end up with $\mathfrak{F}_1 = \mathfrak{F}_2 = \mathfrak{F}$.

In particular, if $\nu$ is a measure absolutely continuous to $\mathbb{P}$, and $\int f\,d\nu = 0$ for all $f \in L^2(\mathfrak{F}_1)$, then $\nu = 0$.

Basically, the issue is that there are a lot of operations that don't enlarge a generated $\sigma$-field, but do enlarge a subspace of $L^2$.  Multiplication is perhaps the most obvious example.